# I need to create my own simple LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I don't understand how to add many components to my `List` and how to address them.

```
public class Element {
    public Object object;
    public int index;
    public Element(Object object){
        this.object = object;
    }
}

public class LinkedList {
    private Element element;
    private int nextLink = 0;
    private int prevLink;
    private int index;


    public void add(Object newElement) {
        nextLink++;
        prevLink++;
        this.index = nextLink - prevLink;
        if (nextLink == 0) {
            prevLink=0;
            this.index = 0;
        }
        else {
            prevLink++;
            this.index = nextLink - prevLink;}
            nextLink++;
            System.out.println(element);
            Element element = new Element(newElement);
            this.element = element;
            if (nextLink == 0) {
                prevLink=0;
                this.index = 0;
            }
            else {
                prevLink++;
                this.index = nextLink - prevLink;}
                nextLink++;
                System.out.println(element);
            }

        public void get(int index) {        
        }
        public void remove(int index) { 
        }
    }


    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedList linked = new LinkedList();
            linked.add("234");
            linked.add("255");
            linked.add("1");
            System.out.println(linked);
            linked.get(1);
        }
    }
```

I have a big problem, because I have only one element on my list and when I want to add new element, my old element rewriting. I don't know how to correct this problem..:((((((

Comment: Element should keep the reference to the next element of the list.. read source of LinkedList if you want to know how it works

Comment: You can't just System.out.println(linked); and expect it to output your list. You must iterate through all your list items using linkedlist.get() (you must implement this function as well)

Answer (score 0):

Generally in linked lists an element contains a reference to the next element in the list. Your `Element` class doesn't seem to have any way to reference the next element in the list.

The wikipedia entry on linked lists might be a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Answer (score 0):

Each Element must contain a link to the next Element. An index is unnecessary and counterproductive.

Start by rewriting your Element class as:

```
public class Element {
    public Object object;
    public Element next;
    public Element(Object object){
    this.object = object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will be very thankful if you explain me how to print my elements, because i have only such Element@d1c9b5 links

Comment: I was trying to do like this, but it didn't work..:(String value = (String) list;

Comment: that's because this is the memory address. You need to have your element class be able to get the data. I recommend something as shown in my code. I am happy to explain it to you. I included conceptual pics

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating something like this. You need references to the next element. As seen in the below code.

E is a generic type. It allows you to create the list node as showin in the code `Listnode<String> l;` The benefit of generics is that you can just as easily create a Listnode of integers. Like this. `Listnode<Integer> integerList;`

```
public class Listnode<E> {
          //*** fields ***
            private E data;
            private Listnode<E> next;

      //*** constructors **/
    // 2 constructors
    public Listnode(E d) {
        this(d, null);
    }

    public Listnode(E d, Listnode n) {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }

  //*** methods ***
    // access to fields
    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Listnode<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    // modify fields
    public void setData(E d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public void setNext(Listnode<E> n) {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

DO THIS TO ACTUALLY IMPLEMENT IT ALL

[image: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~skrentny/cs367-common/readings/Linked-Lists/list-ex1.gif]

[THIS CREATES A LISTNODE OF STRINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8hho.gif)

[image]

NOW this code creates a new node. This node is called 'l' and l points to a "node" that holds the value  "ant" as a string. You can now also see that the next value is null as indicated by a "\"

You can also set/change values at will.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm studying at the course and our teacher didn't explain us what is this <E> . And we have to use only what we already learned:(

Comment: E is a generic type. It allows you to create the list node as showin in the code Listnode<String> l; The benefit of generics is that you can just as easily create a Listnode of integers. Like this. Listnode<Integer> integerList;

Comment: @user3369372 Does this clarify? Don't be afraid to ask

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I think that I understand, but I'm not sure:)))

Comment: Generics allow you to use any primitive type in your Listnode